# Разве новый объект(для этого примера object) не по свойстве constructor наследует значение "Hello"?

Tags: javascript

**Сначала прочтите этот вопрос(вопрос в виде комментарии внутри первого нижеприведенного кода). Если ответ ДА то перейдите и прочтите вторую часть внизу. А если ответ НЕТ, то просто игнорьте вторую часть, но при этом объясните плиз почему НЕТ**

```js
//Это

function F(){
prototype={
b: "Hi"
}
}


//и Это

function F (){
}

F.prototype={
b: "Hi"
}

   // Не одно и тоже ?
```

```js
function F() {

  /*По умолчанию prototype ={
  constructor: F
  } */
  prototype = {
      b: "Hi" // А здесь перезаписывается, то есть удаляется свойство constuctor.
    },
    this.a = "Hello";
}

let object = new F();
console.log(object.prototype == F); //false - потому что перезаписали свойство prototype конструктора F
console.log(object.a) // Hello - А почему тогда выводится "Hello" если мы перезаписали prototype конструктора F

/* Или "Hello" выводится потому что там this(который означает это объект(в данном случае object) перед точкой), а перезаписание ptototype вообще не влияет здесь? 
 То есть перезаписание можеть влиять если я захочу использовать то что внизу */


let object2 = new object.constructor();
console.log(object2.a) //Не выведет "Hello" потому что перезаписали prototype при этом удалив свойство constructor
```

Comment: а почему это должно быть одним и тем же?:) присваивание значения переменной и свойству - никак не связаны

Comment: твой код не соответствует твоим комментариям. Непонятно что именно ты спрашиваешь и как это связано с твоим кодом

Comment: _Не одно и тоже ?_ - да, не одно и то же, нет, не одно и то же. Какой ответ ты ожидаешь? :)

Comment: @Grundu OMG )) "Не одно и то же?" означает "Не равны"? .

Comment: Конечно не равны, с чего бы им быть равными, если выполняются никак не связанные между собой действия

Comment: Не вовремя отправлено мой коммент ( хотела добавить кое-что, но 5 мин истекло) ). Короче это должно было быть отправлено как коммент:  @Grundy  , OMG, нет, не может быть, как непонятно(кстати столько не в одном предложении) )) "Не одно и то же?" означает "Не равны?". Или так скажем, Одно и тоже(Равны) ? - ну ответы были бы такими: Да конечно, равны || Нет конечно, не равны. Богатый русский язык, обожаю этот язык.

Comment: Главная ошибка в приведенном коде - почему-то считать, что `prototype = ...` и  `F.prototype = ...` это одно и то же. На самом деле нет, поэтому дальнейшие рассуждения бессмысленны

Comment: если добавишь в своем коде в самом верху `'use strict'` - даже браузер тебе покажется что это не одно и то же :)

Comment: более того, комментарии во втором сниппете все еще не соответствуют коду, например, в последней строке выводится `Hello`, в то время как в комментарии написано об обратном

Comment: Они одну и ту же функцию выполняют хотя( то есть перезаписывают свойство prototype ). Если для обоих написать console.log(object.prototype==F) ,  то выводится для обоих false.  А что их отличает кроме синтаксиса?

Comment: Ну я же заранее написала что если ответ вопроса Нет, то просто игнорьте второй код ))

Comment: _А что их отличает кроме синтаксиса?_ - то что в одном случае устанавливается свойство для `F`, а в другом - нет

Comment: _Ну я же заранее написала что если ответ вопроса Нет_ - вопрос так плохо сформулирован, что тяжело понять, что конкретно нужно или не нужно игнорировать.

Answer (score 1):

В первой части два совершенно разных кода. В первом происходит инициализация объекта в глобальную переменную prototype. В строгом режиме интерпретатор выкинет ошибку

```
function F(){
 prototype = {  // <=== тут prototype - это переменная из глобальной области видимости
   b: "Hi"
 }
}
```

Во втором - меняется prototype свойства конструктора Object

```
function F (){}

F.prototype = { // <=== это prototype свойство конструктора объекта
  b: "Hi"
}
```